# Invalid audio stream. Exactly one MP3 audio stream is required

Tags: ffmpeg

I've written a small line to concat two mp3 files and add background music to the result. It works quite well, but I'm getting some weird errors. Can anyone identify the cause?

(inside a for loop)

```
ffmpeg -y -i "Input/%%i" -i "Assets/outro.mp3" -filter_complex "[0:a][1:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1;amovie='Assets/music.mp3':loop=999,volume=0.2[s];[0][s]amix=duration=shortest" "tmp.audio.mp3"
```

Errors:

[mp3 @ 000000000059f180] Invalid audio stream. Exactly one MP3 audio stream is required.
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:1 --

Log file: https://pastebin.com/PLnu0Fvn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean to mix the concat output with the music, it should be

`-filter_complex "[0:a][1:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[a];amovie='Assets/music.mp3':loop=999,volume=0.2[s];[a][s]amix=duration=shortest"`

Comment: This works perfectly with no errors, thank you :) could you please help me understand what you changed and what I was doing wrong before?

Comment: I assigned a label to the concat result and then used that in amix. Your command was referencing the source audio for the first input.